# Safe Cast in Crystal Reports Comparison

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports version 14.0.3.613RTM

With SQL Server 2012 onward, if a field has both number and string data, I can use try_convert to compare, i.e.

```
TRY_CONVERT(int, resource_code) > 999999999
```

How do I handle this in Crystal Reports?

I tried:

```
ToNumber({sch_resource.resource_code})
```

But if `resource_code` isn't a number, CR barfs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by [beccasue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/64041/beccasue), I found the solution:

Using a Nested `If` with `IsNumeric` and `ToNumber` worked.

Example of nested Crystal Reports if statement copied from a SO question:
[Nested if else in Crystal Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184169/nested-if-else-in-crystal-reports)

> ```
> if {table1.id} <> 1 then
>    (if {table1.name} <> "a" then
>       var1 := "Hello"
>    else
>       var1 := "Hi";)
> else
>    var1 := "Bye";
> ```

Comment: This (of course) isn't actually an answer to your question. The best way to thank someone is to upvote their answer if it was helpful, and to accept it if it was the one that best resolved your problem. Your example link would be best communicated as a comment on @beccasue 's answer.

Comment: Looks like a proper answer to me, since the other user only commented, without providing an answer - answer. But - @epardee - I'd prefer if you had included the actual code you used.